# put image to image control using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have a base64string result however i don't know how to make the image appears on image control. i used `$('Image1').attr();` but it's not working . Any help thanks

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "PostData.aspx/Photo",
  data: '{Code:"' + res + '"}',
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  success: function(result) {
    $('#Image1').attr('imageurl', 'data:Image/jpg;base64,' + result.d);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`imageurl` is not a standard HTML attribute for the `img` tag. Please assign the value to `src` instead.

```
$('#Image1').attr('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + result.d);
```